# How did Arya not get burned in S8E05, "The Bells"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Arya is clearly in contact with the fire in season 8 Episode 5, “The Bells”, but the next we see of her she is fine again. How did she not get burnt?

Comment: Secret Targ, confirmed.

Comment: [Hollywood plays it fast and loose with hot things](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConvectionSchmonvection).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Arya dives down an alley off of the main street and so is out of the main brunt of the dragon fire. In fact the dragon fire in general doesn’t seem to do too much damage to stuff off of the direct course of it. On top of that she then shelters behind a large rock.

Then using this [excellent analysis from movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100738/45378) we can see that the flames passing in front of Arya are merely a camera trick and that in actual fact the flames weren’t actually that near her.

[image: Arya shelters from the flames frame by frame analysis]

This makes sense as Arya turns a corner and so shelters against the wall and the flames would not get close to the near side wall and instead close in at an angle. 
To avoid showing off my excellent paint skills I’ll borrow the diagram from the other answer on that movies post to demonstrate this.

[image: Diagram showing path of the flames]

Lastly, we can clearly see that the rock Arya hides behind what appears to be unburnt and so that corroborates the theory further.

[image: The rock Arya hides behind]

Comment: That diagram makes the whole plot make sense. +1! :-)

Comment: Of course, this only works with Hollywood Fire.  Real fire would still burn you via proximity, no contact necessary.  Because the heat doesn't just exist in the flame, it rapidly spreads through the air around it, too.  Which we all know from gas stoves, and/or candles, and/or those times we went camping, etc.

Comment: While this is an excellent analysis (+1), the show still had an internal consistency problem since many scenes showed drogon's fire levelling buildings, but other scenes the buildings could block or channel his flames.

Comment: @Paul Most of that can probably be handwaved away with not in direct line of the main line of fire.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Plot armor is usually fireproof.

Comment: It's weird to scroll past an answer and see your own shoddy diagram posted again :)

Comment: @Paul: Other than the direct line of fire argument, not every wall will be as strong as the next. The physics are not as simple as "it always or never works".